# TLS 1.2 connections for the Payment Processor

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

Payment is requesting all traffic we sent to them be TLS 1.2, they are complaining now that we’re using TSL 1.0. For this
The first thing i did was, I have created a Windows 2012 R2 EC2 instance. In the regitry I have added the following under
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL: 
In protocols,
I have created the keys along with Dword,
SSL 2.0 (Client (disabled) server(Enabled),
SSL 3.0 (Client (disabled) server(Enabled), 
TLS 1.1 (client (disabled)-server(Enabled)), 
TLS 1.2 (client (Enabled)- server(Enabled))
After doing this, I restarted the server. Once i restarted, the RDP could able to connect to the server after making the changes. ( I stucked up here)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9zFl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using .NET, you'll need to tell it to use the settings in SCHANNEL. Depending on your .NET version, it'll be something like:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727] "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v2.0.50727] "SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001

Alternatively, you could also use the "SchUseStrongCrypto" key or hard-code the values in ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.

Additional info:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3135244
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/07/12/enable-tls-1-2-protocol-for-reporting-services-with-custom-net-application/#comment-3335